# Novikov condition for Vasicek process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose that we have a money account $S^{(0)}$ with dynamics 
\begin{align}
dS^{(0)}_{t} = r_{t} S^{(0)}_{t}\, dt,
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
dr_t = a(b-r_t)\, dt + \sigma_{r} \, dW_t^{(0)}.
\end{align}
Moreover, suppose that there is a stock $S^{(1)}$ such that
\begin{align}
d S^{(1)}_{t} = \alpha S^{(1)}_{t} \, dt + \sigma S^{(1)}_{t}dW_{t}^{(1)}.
\end{align}
Assume that $a,b,\sigma_{r},\alpha,\sigma>0$ and that the initial values of the processes are known constants and that $W^{(0)}$ and $W^{(1)}$ are independent.

First question: Is $r_{t}$ adapted to the (augmented) natural filtration of $S^{(0)}$ and $S^{(1)}$?

Second question: Given $T>0$, does the Novikov condition hold, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\text{e}^{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\left(\frac{\alpha-r_{t}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}dt}\right]<\infty?
\end{align}